# Gaussian elimination in numerical

Tags: numerical-methods, python

In the following code I have implemented Gaussian elimination without partial pivoting for a general square linear system Ax = b.

However I am looking for some help with implementing the following two requirements,

1) I want to make sure that my function terminates if a zero pivot is encountered.

2) And I want to test it by solving Ax = b where A is a random 100x100 matrix and b is a random 100x1 vector.

Looking for some help with adding these two things into the code I have produced! thanks!

```
 def linearsolver(A,b):
  n = len(A)
  M = A

  i = 0
  for x in M:
   x.append(b[i])
   i += 1

  for k in range(n):
   for i in range(k,n):
     if abs(M[i][k]) > abs(M[k][k]):
        M[k], M[i] = M[i],M[k]
     else:
        pass

   for j in range(k+1,n):
       q = float(M[j][k]) / M[k][k]
       for m in range(k, n+1):
          M[j][m] -=  q * M[k][m]

  x = [0 for i in range(n)]

  x[n-1] =float(M[n-1][n])/M[n-1][n-1]
  for i in range (n-1,-1,-1):
    z = 0
    for j in range(i+1,n):
        z = z  + float(M[i][j])*x[j]
    x[i] = float(M[i][n] - z)/M[i][i]
  print (x)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: This would be a better stackoverflow question, since it is code-based primarily. There are enough of us there that know math, too

Comment: @HackerBoss okay I didn't get a response over there so I figured I would try my luck here, thanks!

Comment: Link the stack overflow question and ill answer it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52749659/adding-details-into-gaussian-elimination-in-python

Comment: @Rhowe, there is the link above!

Comment: @mt12345 iI'm confused about what you're doing in the first for loop.

Comment: do you know how to solve the problem?

Comment: your code isn't even indented and you're using lists instead of numpy arrays...I'm simply trying to get your code to work and make them numpy arrays right now.  I'm also confused why you didn't use them.

Comment: how to solve the problem, I think you're checking for pivots in the second for loops you'd put a conditional statement in there.

Comment: you realize most people use comments and matrices

Comment: seems that I have made some mistakes then, thanks for helping me btw! I will accept your solutuion after you post it

Comment: would you accept a solution if I use code I've made?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51199586/gauss-elimination-to-solve-ax-b-linear-system-matlab/51200548#51200548 this is my matlab with partial pivoting. for reference..

Comment: I can accept it if it is in python and has to 2 criteria I am looking for above

Comment: @RHowe i need to make a version of it that has partial pivoting and one without, so whichever one you can help me with. I made an attempt at wtithout

Comment: Sure, It's a little late but I'll work on that.

Comment: @RHowe thanks for your time, i will gladly accept and upvote your answer

Comment: @RHowe any luck solving my problem?

Comment: @mt12345 sorry I'll get to it in the morning..it's like midnight.

Comment: @RHowe no worries, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm answering this here anyways. People will say you should answer things on Stackoverflow if it is primarily coding, however, mathematical questions on StackOverflow are instantly overlooked.

### Gaussian Elimination without Pivoting

```
import numpy as np
import math


def forward_elimination(A, b, n):
    """
    Calculates the forward part of Gaussian elimination.
    """
    for row in range(0, n-1):
        for i in range(row+1, n):
            factor = A[i,row] / A[row,row]
            for j in range(row, n):
                A[i,j] = A[i,j] - factor * A[row,j]

            b[i] = b[i] - factor * b[row]

        print('A = \n%s and b = %s' % (A,b))
    return A, b

def back_substitution(a, b, n):
    """"
    Does back substitution, returns the Gauss result.
    """
    x = np.zeros((n,1))
    x[n-1] = b[n-1] / a[n-1, n-1]
    for row in range(n-2, -1, -1):
        sums = b[row]
        for j in range(row+1, n):
            sums = sums - a[row,j] * x[j]
        x[row] = sums / a[row,row]
    return x

def gauss(A, b):
    """
    This function performs Gauss elimination without pivoting.
    """
    n = A.shape[0]

    # Check for zero diagonal elements
    if any(np.diag(A)==0):
        raise ZeroDivisionError(('Division by zero will occur; '
                                  'pivoting currently not supported'))

    A, b = forward_elimination(A, b, n)
    return back_substitution(A, b, n)
```

### Generates random matrix with given condition number

```
def gen_rand_matrix(m,n,kappa):
#
#
    k= min(m,n)
    (Q1,R1) = np.linalg.qr(np.random.rand(m,m))
    (Q2,R2) = np.linalg.qr(np.random.rand(n,n))

    U = Q1[0:m,0:k]
    V = Q2[0:k,0:n]
    j=k-1

    l = kappa**(1/j)
    x1 = np.arange(0,j+1)
    x2 = np.flip(x1,axis=0)
    sing = np.power(l,x2)
    S = np.diag(sing)
    Vt = np.transpose(V)

    M = np.dot(np.dot(U,S),Vt)
    return M
```

### This part here is testing

```
kappa = 1/(math.exp(1e-3)-1)
m=100

A  = gen_rand_matrix(m,m,kappa)
x = np.random.rand(m,1)
b = np.dot(A,x)
xhat1 = gauss(A,b)

xerror1 = np.linalg.norm(xhat1-x)/np.linalg.norm(x)
```

### Matlab Implementation Of Partial Pivoting From a Numerical Methods Book

There is an implementation [here](https://www.math.wvu.edu/~sherm/m420/Notes/GaussianEliminationExample20110207.pdf)

Comment: thanks for this, so how do I make sure that my function terminates if a zero pivot is encountered. and how can I test it by solving Ax = b where A is a random 100x100 matrix and b is a random 100x1 vector.

Comment: i will accept the answer for now anyways

Comment: that would be great!

Comment: thanks for that edit, im a little confused how i use that above code you made first to test it with a random 100x100 matrix A and a randon vector b 100x1, is it something i need to put into the code? could you edit that in

Comment: all i want to do is just test that

Comment: sorry I formatted my code wrong when I put it into this website

Comment: when I copy and paste your code into my python program there is no output, shouldn't there be a random 100x100 matrix and a random 100x1 matrix evaluated using gaussian elimination?

Comment: I don't know what ide you're using or what error you're getting or if you even ran the code.

Comment: http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~haber/math315/chap3.pdf there is an implementation here on page 77 in matlab I don't want to spend the rest of my day debugging.